# Relative URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a menu and each menu item has a picture.
This is a piece of code from one item:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    <!--
    function changeImage(element, hoverImage) {
        document.getElementById(element).src = hoverImage;
    }
    // -->
</script>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Menu" %>
<ul id="navmenu">
    <li><a id="default" runat="server" href="~/Default.aspx" 
        onmouseover="changeImage('sideBar_Menu1_Image7', 'Images/Calendar32x32.png');"
        onmouseout="changeImage('sideBar_Menu1_Image7', 'Images/Calendar24x24.png');">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 32px; width: 32px">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar24x24.png" />
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="CALENDAR" meta:resourcekey="Label6Resource1"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </a></li>
```

When I run my app, when I am in the root folder the images on the menu will load, but when I am somewhere else, they will not load anymore. Is there a way it can be done from js? I wouldn't really want now to start making so many css classes to solve the issue.

LATER EDIT:
the solution consists of a BL project, a Jobs project and the website that's named CRM...when ran on the local machine, it works fine if I write /CRM/Images/Image.png, but when published it deos not work...if I write /Images/Image.png it doesn't work on the localhost but it works when published...I will not know the paths as it will be deployed to more clients, each of them will have a different path...but I have found a solution and lower is the code

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution that solves my problem:
the new code will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
<!--
function changeImage(element, toReplace, withReplace) {
    var str = document.getElementById(element).src;
    document.getElementById(element).src = str.replace(toReplace, withReplace)
}
// -->
```

```
<%@ control language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" codefile="Menu.ascx.cs" inherits="UserControls_Menu" %>
<ul id="navmenu">
    <li><a id="default" runat="server" href="~/Default.aspx" onmouseover="changeImage('sideBar_Menu1_Image7', 'Calendar24x24.png', 'Calendar32x32.png');"
        onmouseout="changeImage('sideBar_Menu1_Image7', 'Calendar32x32.png', 'Calendar24x24.png');">
        <div class="divImage">
            <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar24x24.png" />
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; padding-top: 3px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="CALENDAR" meta:resourcekey="Label6Resource1"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
    </a></li>
```

The images have to be in the same folder, in my case they always are, but I suppose everybody puts them in the same folder...so there shouldn't be a problem
Thanks for the help though

Comment: You could also use the <base> tag with the url, that becomes the base url for the relative urls. For ex. `<base href="http://<%= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath%>" />` and then all you relative urls will work without any issues (Make sure all the relative urls start without a slash(/))

Answer (score 6):

Prefix your URL with a `/` to indicate a relative path:

```
/Images/Calendar32x32.png
^ Add slash
```

**Corrected code:**

```
<a id="default" runat="server" href="~/Default.aspx" 
  onmouseover="changeImage('sideBar_Menu1_Image7', '/Images/Calendar32x32.png');"
  onmouseout="changeImage('sideBar_Menu1_Image7', '/Images/Calendar24x24.png');">
```

Comment: yes, I have tried that, it didn't work...

Comment: @bokkie, Do you get an error in the console? This ***is*** the proper way to specify a relative path in JS.

Comment: no, I don't get any error...but with "/" the image on hover disappears

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem...the lower answer + comments get to the bottom of the problem, I will just have to find a solution

Comment: @bokkie, Respectfully, it **does** answer your original question. You asked how to specify a relative path in JS - my answer does that. It seems that you've added requirements and additional information along the way using comments. Obviously, this is not the best way to get questions answered on SO. My answer answers your original question.

Comment: isn't the point in the whole story to solve this issue and help the others too? if you read lower you can find that James Montagne digged deeper and found the cause of the problem...so people come, read this and know what is wrong...so what you consider an answer was of no help to the problem addressed. but thanks for the effort, I am sure everybody will appreciate it

Comment: @bokkie, No, that's not the point. The point is for the person who asks a question to properly detail their needs and requirements so they can receive accurate and correct answers - only then does it help the community. Forcing users to read all the comments in a thread so they understand your requirements helps no one. This is why you received 5 answers that were incorrect (based on your requirements).

Comment: so if you don't know the origin of the problem you shouldn't ask for help...ok, I see...well, then after the help or our friend, I will edit the text of my post, to say that we know the cause of the problem, and that lower they can find the solution...thank you for enlighting me my dear friend

Comment: @bokkie, It seems like you think I'm trying to be rude - I'm certainly not and I apologize if I came across that way. I'm simply trying to help you understand how to ask better questions so you can get better answers. If you don't know the origin of the problem, give as much detail as you can (e.g. The extra details that you put in the comments but not your original question). If you don't feel like you can accurately express your requirements, I suggest starting in one of the chat rooms so you can have back and forth with people that can help. Welcome to SO, I hope you enjoy the site!

Comment: if I would have known the "extra details" be sure I would have written them in the original post...those came to the surface after the help of James...and if someone has the same problem and tries to solve it for half a day and finds this post, believe me, he will look through the comments..I know I did one everything that was related to this...unfortunately I couldn't find an answer, but fortunately I came up with a solution later, based on James' help...and I posted it...but I will update the original post too so it will be clearer for the ones who look for this issue

Answer (score 2):

Start your relative urls with `/`.  This will start from the root of the site instead of from the current location.

EDIT:  Based on the comments, if the "root" you are referring to is not the root of your site then you need to include the path to your sub-site in your relative URL.

For example, if your URL you are referring to as "root" is `http://www.somesite.com/some/sub/site`, then your relative URLs would have to be `/some/sub/site...`.  If you simply use `/...` you will be taken to `http://www.somesite.com/...` instead of `http://www.somesite.com/some/sub/site/...`.

---

Another alternative, depending on your folder setup, would be to use `..` to go up one level.

For instance, if you have a page `.../CMR/pages/something.aspx` and within that page you want to point to `.../CMR/Images/someimg` then you can use `../Images/someimg`.  The `..` will take you one level up.

Comment: Perhaps if you give us an example of what your application URLs look like it would help.  This does work, it could be that you're not at the root of your URL, but a sub-site?

Comment: CRM\Admin\Admin.aspx  CRM\Admin\otherfiles    CRM\Images\.png images   CRM\Default.aspx  CRM\ other .aspx files...the application starts in Default.aspx...so when I am there, I see the images right...also the hovers, but when I go into CRM\Admin\Admin.aspx by pressing the Admin button on the menu, the hovers don't work anymore...hope you understand what I mean, otherwise please let me know............... CRM is one of the 3 projects, but that is not relevant in our case

Comment: I would disagree about it not being relevant.  If your URL is `http://www.something.com/CRM/...` then your relative URLs need to be `/CMR/...` since your "project" root is not the site root. `/` is the root (without the CRM).

Comment: yes, you are right, and I wanted to edit my reply but it was too late:) ... so I have two projects, one BL and one with Jobs and the third is the website that we are talking about...so when in my code I write the path /CRM/Images/Image.png it works well...and I suppose if I would leave it /Images/Image.png it would work when I would publish it at the client...the thing is, how do I make it for both to work?

Comment: Answer updated with some additional info/ideas based on your comments.

Comment: http://localhost:2138/CRM/Default.aspx this is where it starts now...as I said above, if I do it /CRM/Images/myImage.png it will work for me, but not when published...if I do only /Images/myImage.png will not work for me but I think it will work when it is published...I would need it to wokr both ways, wouldn't I? therefore I need a solution to have both...anyway, I think we got closer to solving the problem :) "../Images" I tried before, didn't work

Comment: If the paths are completely different on each environment you'll need some sort of server-side configuration to swap between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score -1):

try to write "~/" before Images/Calendar32x32.png.

Comment: have tried that too, it didn't work... as far as I understand, Javascript doesn't know how to interpret the "~" ?